# Codeigniter URL Dilemma

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am having issues with the urls. I took the .htaccess code from the user guide to remove the index.php from the url and I have removed it from the config as well. Now here is the problem. I have a controller named “main” and a function inside called “join” which simply display the view. Now if I go to `http://localhost/myfolder` it loads the index view just fine. However if I try to go to `http://localhost/myfolder/main/join` or `http://localhost/myfolder/join` it gives me a 404 error. But `http://localhost/myfolder/index.php/main/join` works however without loading any css from my header file, but the footer is still loaded. Which I am very confused about. How can I possibly fix it so it just works with main/join? I will use routing later to make it just /join however I need the css to load like it does with my “index” view but not with my “join” view. Also localhost/myfolder/main gives me a 404 error as well. All I did was take the code from the user guide and paste it in .htaccess Any help guys?

Comment: Maybe post the relevant code? As it stands, your question is kind of vague and may be closed.

Comment: No code is really needed, if you know codeigniter that is, but the problem is fixed, thank you.

Comment: So what was the issue? Please feel free to post the solution (and mark it as accepted), for the benefit of future visitors. Or you can delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Question is little confusing but let me try to answer what I got.

**Question 1. Make 'localhost/myfolder/main/join' working.**

You mainly need to remove index.php. Do the following:

**a. (Very important)** Make sure apache's rewrite module is enabled. IF you are using wamp, go to 'Apache'>'Apache modules' and make sure 'rewrite_module' is checked.

**b.** In code igniter, open file application>config>config.php. Search the line:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Remove index.php from there. Line must be

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**c.** on myfolder, make a file .htaccess and add following code there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now URL 'localhost/myfolder/main/join' must be working.

**Question 2: Load CSS**

To load css, user following code under head section of your view:

```
<?php echo link_tag('style/style.css');?>
```

Make sure style/style.css is present in root folder; 'myfolder' in your case.

Hope this helps,

Kapil.